# Checking for any column updated in triggers

Tags: sql-server

I need to validate in a trigger on SQL Server 2008R2 if any of the columns was updated.

Basically I have a table for example `Employee` and `EmployeeHistory`. Any insert/update/delete on `Employee` table should generate a record in the history one. I don't care about the column. So for example, can I use

```
If Columns_Updated()

    insert into history???
else
    nothing?
```

Is this the right way of checking this? Is there any other function? `UPDATE()` is only for a specific column. What's the best practice to do this? I'm sure that I'm not the first one that want to create a history record of a table!

Comment: Not sure I follow: the `UPDATE` trigger will only fire ***IF*** there was a change - any change. So the case that the update trigger was fired, but nothing changed on that row, doesn't exist ...

Comment: By "column was updated", do you mean "column was listed in an update statement" or "value of the column was actually changed by update statement"?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Columns_Updated()` is ok.

But if nothing was updated, your trigger won't even fire, will it?

What are you trying to do in end?

Comment: I found this article about some issues using this function http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d881158-31a9-458f-9474-f9f68d5dddde/dont-use-columnsupdated-trigger-update-function?forum=transactsql I wanted to be sure that the function is working ok in any case.